# Removing old rusty single hole faucet - please help!

Tags: faucet

We are trying to remove our old Kohler faucet.  We are running into issues on how to remove the stem on the underside.  I have a picture attached.
We are not sure which piece to take out?  There are three parts that we see: the rusty top part, the middle brass part, then the smaller ring.  Do we need to remove all 3? 
Any advice appreciated! Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how SE networks operate, then either accept an answer, provide your own, or close the question to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

The brass ring piece with the two holes in it is the part that needs to be removed. It should be able to be unthreaded from the tubing part that the hoses go up into.

Generally a special spanner wrench with two pegs on it would be used to turn the brass ring. The pegs would engage the two holes in the ring. Alternatively you could use an adjustable pliers or plumbers sink wrench to grasp the ring on its outer edge.

Comment: Happy Thanksgiving!  Thank you for taking time out to offer your advice.  Gives me a bit of hope in humanity in this crazy world.

Answer (score 0):

Just the brass nut. A little penetrating oil or WD-40 might help. There are special wrenches for this purpose, but a large adjustable pliers might do.

Comment: Apologies for a delayed thank you! We have a toddler at home and didn’t want the hassle for too long.  We ended up hiring a handyman who fixed it for a reasonable price.  Happy Thanksgiving!  Thank you for taking time out to help a stranger!